# DiscoverMeteor: what is the purpose of bundling?

Tags: meteor, bundle

In Chapter 2.5 of Discover Meteor by Tom Coleman, the instructions for deploying to EC2 require me to first bundle the app, move the tarball one directory up, then unzip that tarball again, before running node on the app.

This seems rather a tedious procedure as I'll have to bundle and unzip after every commit to test the app. Also, isn't this just the same thing as moving the entire app one directory up, or does bundling then unzipping do some magic that makes it run right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bundling creates a production application, optimized to run on the live environment, while your working directory is more suitable for development. For example, bundled app only have one js and one css file instead of tens to hundreds.

Additionally, bundled app contains all the engine needed to run with plain node, so that you may run it in an environment without Meteor.